# Query works in Sql Server Management Studio, but not ColdFusion with MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, ssms

**Update:** Strange clue--If I change table1 to table3, it works in CF. I figured dropping the table would completely clear it out. But somehow it is being a zombie. How to fix?

This is my iteration of the question "Query works in Sql Server Management Studio, but not in...."

This code, copied and pasted, works in SSMS, but not in a Coldfusion query. I get:

> Error Executing Database Query.
>   [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Invalid column name 'StudentID'.

**SQL:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.##table1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##table1

CREATE TABLE ##table1
(
    [RecordID]      [integer] IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    [StudentID]     [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [CourseNumber]  [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [CompDateTime]  [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [SystemInfo]    [varchar](250) NULL,
    [WriteTime]     [datetime] default GETDATE() NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [StudentID], [CourseNumber], [CompDateTime]
    )
);

INSERT INTO ##table1
        (StudentID, CourseNumber, CompDateTime, SystemInfo, WriteTime)
VALUES  ('aaa', '111', GETDATE(), 'yes', GETDATE()),
        ('bbb', '222', GETDATE(), 'yes', GETDATE()),
        ('ccc', '333', GETDATE(), 'yes', GETDATE())

select * from ##table1;

drop table ##table1
```

### **Edit 1 -- more error info:**

**Full CF error**

> The error occurred in
>   //hanford/data/sitedata/WBT/wbt-dev/RecordsCollector/records-collector.cfm:
>   line 54 Called from
>   //hanford/data/sitedata/WBT/wbt-dev/RecordsCollector/records-collector.cfm:
>   line 1 Called from
>   //hanford/data/sitedata/WBT/wbt-dev/RecordsCollector/records-collector.cfm:
>   line 54 Called from
>   //hanford/data/sitedata/WBT/wbt-dev/RecordsCollector/records-collector.cfm:
>   line 1   52 :  53 :  54 :  55 :  56 : 
>   IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.##table1') IS NOT NULL

**Full stack trace**

> at
>   cfrecords2dcollector2ecfm1769031009._factor5(//hanford/data/sitedata/WBT/wbt-dev/RecordsCollector/records-collector.cfm:54)
>   at
>   cfrecords2dcollector2ecfm1769031009.runPage(//hanford/data/sitedata/WBT/wbt-dev/RecordsCollector/records-collector.cfm:1)
>   at
>   cfrecords2dcollector2ecfm1769031009._factor5(//hanford/data/sitedata/WBT/wbt-dev/RecordsCollector/records-collector.cfm:54)
>   at
>   cfrecords2dcollector2ecfm1769031009.runPage(//hanford/data/sitedata/WBT/wbt-dev/RecordsCollector/records-collector.cfm:1)
>
> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC
>   Driver][SQLServer]Invalid column name 'StudentID'.    at
>   macromedia.jdbc.sqlserverbase.dda4.b(Unknown Source)  at
>   macromedia.jdbc.sqlserverbase.dda4.a(Unknown Source)  at
>   macromedia.jdbc.sqlserverbase.dda3.b(Unknown Source)  at
>   macromedia.jdbc.sqlserverbase.dda3.a(Unknown Source)  at
>   macromedia.jdbc.sqlserver.tds.ddr.v(Unknown Source)   at
>   macromedia.jdbc.sqlserver.tds.ddr.a(Unknown Source)   at
>   macromedia.jdbc.sqlserver.tds.ddr.a(Unknown Source)   at
>   macromedia.jdbc.sqlserver.ddj.l(Unknown Source)   at
>   macromedia.jdbc.sqlserverbase.ddde.e(Unknown Source)  at
>   macromedia.jdbc.sqlserverbase.ddde.a(Unknown Source)  at
>   macromedia.jdbc.sqlserverbase.ddde.v(Unknown Source)  at
>   macromedia.jdbc.sqlserverbase.ddde.r(Unknown Source)  at
>   macromedia.jdbc.sqlserverbase.ddde.execute(Unknown Source)    at
>   coldfusion.server.j2ee.sql.JRunStatement.execute(JRunStatement.java:348)
>     at coldfusion.sql.Executive.executeQuery(Executive.java:1364)   at
>   coldfusion.sql.Executive.executeQuery(Executive.java:1127)    at
>   coldfusion.sql.Executive.executeQuery(Executive.java:1058)    at
>   coldfusion.sql.SqlImpl.execute(SqlImpl.java:341)  at
>   coldfusion.tagext.sql.QueryTag.executeQuery(QueryTag.java:915)    at
>   coldfusion.tagext.sql.QueryTag.doEndTag(QueryTag.java:590)    at
>   cfrecords2dcollector2ecfm1769031009._factor5(\hanford\data\sitedata\WBT\wbt-dev\RecordsCollector\records-collector.cfm:54)
>     at
>   cfrecords2dcollector2ecfm1769031009.runPage(\hanford\data\sitedata\WBT\wbt-dev\RecordsCollector\records-collector.cfm:1)
>     at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)  at
>   coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:418)     at
>   coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)     at
>   coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:399)
>     at
>   coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
>     at
>   coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
>     at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:94)  at
>   coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)     at
>   coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
>     at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)    at
>   coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)     at
>   coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)     at
>   coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
>     at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)    at
>   coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:201)    at
>   coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
>     at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)   at
>   coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
>     at
>   coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
>     at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)   at
>   jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)    at
>   jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)   at
>   jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)    at
>   jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
>     at
>   jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
>     at
>   jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
>     at
>   jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
>     at
>   jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
>     at
>   jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
>     at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)

Comment: May I ask why global temp table and not `#table1`?

Comment: Is this a contrived example or are you actually doing this (query)? If so, why? - Have you executed this with a trace running? How are you executing it in your environment?

Comment: @lad2025 The ## comes from coldfusion (you need to escape #). But it works fine if I use #table1. I just wanted to do no editing after cut and paste.

Comment: Do you use `##table1` in multiple places (different table definition)?

Comment: @AlexK. I have a goal. My code "isn't working." So I'm trying to break it down into bits that I can get working, and build back up to the real thing. Standard debugging, right? I'm executing it in a .cfm file. Just the exact query above, except inside `<cfquery>...</cfquery>`. I have debugging on. I'll post the full trace.

Comment: Very strangeness!!!!! If I change `table1` to `table3` it works. Please explain...

Comment: @lad2025 No. Purely testing here. See update though. If I change table1 to table3, it works in CF. I'm dropping table1, but somehow it is stuck in the system. How to clear it out?

Comment: @abalter I am not sure how your CF code looks like but one hint: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/379152 look carefully at table names

Comment: You might want to change your approach.  Put all that sql into a stored procedure and call it from CF.

Comment: Right after you create the table, select * from it and dump the columnlist.

Comment: DATA EXPLORER!!!! I never new. It rocks! http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/379205/testing-create-fill-temp-table